# Jquery .ajax beforeSend seems to remove the click event handler from a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm trying to work with wordpress to stop an ajax request sent by Jquery and re-submit it with some additional data.

Here's how its working:

- User clicks a submit button.
- Wordpress submits the ajax request
- I have a global `beforeSend` function set up using `.ajaxSetup` in this way:

  `$.ajaxSetup( {beforeSend: monitorRequests } );`
- When wordpress submits the request, its intercepted by my function, which calls another function that submits another ajax request, while `monitorRequests`' returns false, which cancels the original ajax request.
- My own ajax request is sent, without any problems.

However here's the issue. After doing this once, if the user clicks the submit button again, wordpress's click handler is not called. I'm wondering why this is, whether this has anything to do with the ajax request being cancelled? Or anything else? What should I do to make it so that the click handler continues to be called?

Comment: are you removing/changing the button at all? if so, that may be removing the click event. however I can't really tell since no code is provided.

Comment: @kennypu I'm not doing anything to the button except adding/removing a css class to it..

Comment: Ahh.. it seems wordpress disables it during the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, Wordpress disables the button during the ajax request, and it remains disabled since wordpress's callback is never called.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajaxSetup globally affects ajax calls in your page. You have no idea how many AJAX implemented in WP plugins and How each its custom implement.

Try narrow your scope to specific element. You may uses

```
$('.submit').bind('click', function(){ /* your fn */ }); 
//You can have many 'click' binding eg..
$('.submit').bind('click', function(){ /* another */ }); 
$('.submit').bind('click', function(){ /* yet another */ });
```

insert your script before existing one. You function will be called first.